# Display 'print preferences' dialog in Win32

Tags: windows, printing

Currently, I'm using PrintDlg to display a print dialog. I have created my own version of this and need to know how to just display the printer specific "print preferences" dialog that you can get to by clicking the "Preferences" button in the PrintDlg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I was after here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183350(v=vs.85).aspx
AdvancedDocumentProperties